# How to fix no-unsafe-any rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint, typescript-types

I'm using [TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) to lint my Angular TypeScript code. I enabled [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/) rule, as it seems like a good rule to me to never assume anything about properties of type `any`.

The problem is the rule reports errors on some of my code, which I'm unable to fix in any way other than disabling the rule. Example of a code that's invalid according to that rule below.

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<{}>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
  return next
    .handle(request)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error && error.status === httpCodeUnauthorized) {
          // Auto logout if unathorized
          this.authenticationService.logout();
        }

        const errorMessage = (error.error && error.error.message) || error.statusText;

        return throwError(errorMessage);
      }),
    );
}
```

Linter reports 4 errors on 2 lines:

```
ERROR: /home/robert/programming/npc/gui/src/app/core/authentication/unauthorized.interceptor.ts[24, 24]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.
ERROR: /home/robert/programming/npc/gui/src/app/core/authentication/unauthorized.interceptor.ts[29, 33]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.
ERROR: /home/robert/programming/npc/gui/src/app/core/authentication/unauthorized.interceptor.ts[29, 48]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.
ERROR: /home/robert/programming/npc/gui/src/app/core/authentication/unauthorized.interceptor.ts[29, 72]: Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'
```

2 problematic lines are:

- `if (error && error.status === httpCodeUnauthorized) {`
- `const errorMessage = (error.error && error.error.message) || error.statusText;`

The root of the problem is that `error` argument of a handler given to [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) ([Rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) library function) has `any` type. I understand `error` can be of any type, so it's unsafe to assume it has any properties defined, but I'm first checking for the presence of those properties before actually refering to them, which seems safe to me.

What can/should I do to convince the linter/TypeScript compiler that it's safe and pass the rule?

Comment: If you just wrap this lines into `if (error) { ... }`, will the problem persist?

Comment: @Cerberus Unfortunately yes, it still reports 4 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Angular the error should always be in  of type [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse%20HttpErrorResponse)

```
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
//...
}
```

That said, in your code you look into `error.error` which is defined as `any`  in `HttpErrorResponse` thus there you should probably use type guard to check and cast it to Error object. Not there is no need to define the `Error` - it should be defined by typescript base types.

```
function isError(value: any | undefined): value is Error {
  return error && ((error as Error).message !== undefined);
}
```

then use it in

```
const errorMessage = isError(error.error) ? error.error.message : error.statusText;
```

Comment: It got rid of the `no-unsafe-any` error indeed. But then the linter was reporting:  `ERROR: (strict-type-predicates) /home/robert/programming/npc/gui/src/app/core/authentication/unauthorized.interceptor.ts[15, 20]: Expression is always true.` on line `return error && ((error as Error).message !== undefined);`. I removed the comparison operator changing it to `return error && (error as Error).message;` and the error is gone. I cannot understand why. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, when you *know* that `error` always has a specific type, you can just annotate the type. If you can not be sure, you can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

**Type annotation**

With a type annotation, you can simply *tell* the compiler, that you expect `error` to be of a certain type. You can avoid the type `any` completely with this approach:

```
interface Error {
    status: string,
    statusText: string,
    error: { message: string | undefined } | undefined;
}

catchError((error: Error | undefined) => {
    //...
}
```

**Type guard**

You can use a type guard whenever a value *could* be of a certain type, but doesn't necessarily *have* to be of that type. The type guard will check for the type and within the following block, the variable will be of that checked type:

```
function isError(value: any | undefined): value is Error {
    return error && ((error as Error).status !== undefined);
}

catchError(error => {
    if (isError(error)) {
        //Inside this block, error will be of type Error
    }
}
```

Comment: With type annotation, what will happen if `error` is not of type `Error`? Will it raise a runtime error? Also both solutions feel like a bit like overkill to me, as situations like that will be numerous, while each one of them would require declaration of different type annotation or type guard.

Comment: A type annotation is stripped in the JS code. It will raise no error for being the wrong type, but probably your program will not work as expected. And a type annotation is not overkill, it's just TS (and if you choose `noImplicityAny` as an option quite common). A type guard provides additional functionality, namely different execution paths based on type.