# How to fix no-unsafe-any for the decorator @HostListener

Tags: angular, tslint

ng lint complains for the below code, the no-unsafe-any is set to true, and we want to use this rule.

Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'

What can I do to remove the linting error for the below code

```
  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  public onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.shiftKey && event.code === KEY_CODES.KEY_S) {
      // service call method - with return type as 'void'
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383082/how-to-fix-no-unsafe-any-rule

Comment: Yes I did, but this is specific to the decorators as they always return of type 'any' , can we cast it some way.